# Bash error "command not found" running a command stored in var

Tags: linux, bash, gruntjs

**Context:**

I want to run a command stored in a variable in bash.

My bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -----------------------------------------------
# ---                COMMANDS                 ---
# ---              Vanilla style              ---
# -----------------------------------------------
GRUNT="node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt"
LS="ls"
# -----------------------------------------------
# ---                COMMANDS                 ---
# ---              Using Docker               ---
# -----------------------------------------------
GRUNT="docker exec compose_custom-node_1 node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt"
LS="docker exec compose_custom-node_1 ls"


# ***********************************************
# ***                Execution                ***
# ***********************************************
# -----------------------------------------------
# Compile SCSS using Grunt
# -----------------------------------------------
echo "Building CSS from Sass files..."
echo "$(docker exec compose_custom-node_1 ls -l)"
echo "$($LS -l)"
$($GRUNT sass)
```

**Problem:**

When I run this bash file, the `grunt sass` command throws an error:

> `mybash.sh: line 25: $'\E[4mRunning' : command not found`

Whole return of my bash:

```
darckcrystale@kermit:/var/www/my_folder$ ./my_bash.sh
Building CSS from Sass files...
total 188
-rw-rw-r--   1 node node  3627 May  2 19:00 Gruntfile.js
drwxr-xr-x 282 root root 12288 May  3 12:12 node_modules
drwxr-xr-x   4 node node  4096 May  2 18:39 sass
total 188
-rw-rw-r--   1 node node  3627 May  2 19:00 Gruntfile.js
drwxr-xr-x 282 root root 12288 May  3 12:12 node_modules
drwxr-xr-x   4 node node  4096 May  2 18:39 sass
my_bash.sh: ligne 25: $'\E[4mRunning' : commande introuvable
```

**Investigation:**

The commands `echo "$(docker exec compose_custom-node_1 ls -l)"` and `echo "$($LS -l)"` seem to work, but not the `$($GRUNT sass)`.

If I run `docker exec compose_custom-node_1 node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt` in a terminal, I see this output:

```
Running "sass:app1" (sass) task
Running "sass:sticky-app2" (sass) task
Done, without errors.
```

**Question:**

Do you have a clue for me? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you run `docker exec compose_custom-node_1 node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt sass` in a terminal? That appears to be what your problem command is running

Comment: @arco444 same as running `docker exec compose_custom-node_1 node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt`

Comment: As often with this type of question, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use a function to store complex commands than a variable,

```
grunt() {
    docker exec compose_custom-node_1 node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt "$@"
}
```

and call this as just

```
grunt "saas"
```

wherever needed in your script. See [BashFAQ-050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) which talks about this exact requirement on complex cases.

Comment: In my case, I have to add a parameter to the `GRUNT` command : `sass`. How to do this with the creation of a function?

Comment: @darckcrystale: simple, just pass the argument